# How to pass listbox items as arguments to a method in c#?

Tags: c#, listbox

For example i have these values stored in the listbox.

```
int pid = (int)reader["pid"];
string FirstName = (string)reader["Fname"];
string LastName = (string)reader["Lname"];
string gender = (string)reader["gender"];
string address = (string)reader["address"];
string email = (string)reader["email"];
string item = string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} -{3} - {4} - {5}" pid,FirstName, LastName,gender,address,email);
this.listBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

How do i pass these items to another class method ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Either as single string or as a custom class with these properties(preferred) or as a `string[]`/`List<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it like that:

```
public void YourMethod(ListBox.ObjectCollection items)
```

using:

```
YourMethod(listBox1.Items);
```

**UPD:** I created a windows form with empty listbox and 1 button. Clicking on button fills the listbox. Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var itemGenerator = new ItemGenerator();
            itemGenerator.AddItems(listBox1);
        }
    }
```

ItemGenerator class:

```
public class ItemGenerator
    {
        private readonly string[] items = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

        public void AddItems(ListBox listBox)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

ItemGenerator has method `AddItems` which has ListBox in parameter. This method is called in Form1 class, so you can directly give a ListBox to processing.

Comment: I am actually running an sql query in myMethod but i want to dispaly the query result in the windows form .How would i do it ?

Comment: @deepaas according to code from your question, you already have an access to your form (you are using this.listBox1) in this method. So I suppose you can add/remove controls on your windows form. Or maybe the problem is that listBox doesn't show these results? please clarify

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass list to a windows form ?